# Translate SPARQL-TO-SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, rdf, sparql, semantic-web

I am doing an experiment to query RDF data on top of existing Relational DBMS's. So, Does anyone know a tool to translate SPARQL queries to SQL?

Thanks all.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow (tool and library requests are, in general).  There are a number of SPARQL systems that support relational databases as a backend, though.  What have you found out about how they translate SPARQL queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for tools providing W3C standard R2RML e.g. D2RQ.

Comment: Just a note: An alternative syntax to R2RML with the goal of being more human friendly is offered by [Sparqlify](https://github.com/AKSW/Sparqlify) - see [here](https://github.com/GeoKnow/LinkedGeoData/blob/master/linkedgeodata-core/src/main/resources/org/aksw/linkedgeodata/sml/LinkedGeoData-Triplify-IndividualViews.sml) for a sophisticated mapping; we are also working on a converter to and from R2RML.